# Css3 transition not works

Tags: css

css

```
.score {
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.score-big {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
}
```

js

```
$('.score').addClass('score-big')
```

scale applying but without transition. When i toggling scale in chrome console, transition works. What problem?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/6vBtv/

Comment: its ok bro, your just missing a `;` terminator.